# 'str' object is not callable Django

Tags: python, django

I'm new to Django and thought I'd go through a few tutorials before branching out on my own. I'm trying to program the calendar app described here: http://lightbird.net/dbe/cal1.html. However, their URLconfigs don't seem to be working for me as I get the following error:

```
TypeError at /admin/

'str' object is not callable

Request Method:         GET
Request URL:    http://ec2-23-20-82-228.compute-1.amazonaws.com:8000/admin/
Django Version:     1.4
Exception Type:     TypeError
Exception Value:    

'str' object is not callable

Exception Location:     /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py in get_response, line 111
Python Executable:  /usr/bin/python
Python Version:         2.7.3
```

If anyone could point me in the right direction, it'd be greatly appreciated!

Comment: More could would be very helpful -- at some point, you have a string instead of a function. Find that and fix it, and you should be OK.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm pretty sure your error is caused by a wrong url conf, the link you posted describes only 2 urlpatterns not the entire url conf:

```
(r"^(\d+)/$", "main"),
(r"", "main"),
```

You can only refer to a string "main" if you setup the prefix correctly, so in your case you probably have a structure like:

```
/project
    /app
        views.py
        urls.py
```

your url conf should be:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('app.views',
    (r"^(\d+)/$", "main"),
    (r"", "main"),
)
```

You can also import the function directly like so:

```
from app.views import main

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    (r"^(\d+)/$", main),
    (r"", main),
)
```

I think it's also bad practice to have two urls pointing to the same view, I would rather create a redirect for the second one and let the view determine if there's parameters to handle

Comment: Do I need to do anything to the urls.py under project? Sorry, I'm completely new at this.

Comment: Maybe you should try the Django tutorial if you are not familiar with its MVC. It will help you understand https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/intro/tutorial01/